# right to left languages in libreoffic

Tags: libreoffice

How to write both English and another language which is right to left in a **line**. **No more talk they know what I am looking for  :-(** But If you persist I say when you type a language which is right to left and then change to engliglish the display format is not correct. ps: I use Libreoffic on 14.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answer to this question is here [Languages Using Complex Text Layout](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Languages_Using_Complex_Text_Layout)

> Ctrl+Shift+D or Ctrl+Right Shift Key - switch to right-to-left text entry
>
> Ctrl+Shift+A or Ctrl+Left Shift Key - switch to left-to-right text
>   entry